# npm downloading hundreds of packages?

Tags: npm

I'm working on an Angular2 (currently on RC1) project in Visual Studio 2015; and straining my understanding of NPM.

Looking in the Dependencies/npm folder, and /node_modules there are *hundreds* of npm packages.  Most of which are labeled as `extraneous` by Visual Studio (in Dependencies/npm)

I went through and removed all the extraneous packages manually (npm prune did nothing).

I apparently accidentally removed a non-extraneous package, which I attempted to restore.  NPM went ahead and re-downloaded all 500+ extraneous packages again...

What am I missing?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MySite",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Site",
  "repository": "./src",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-promise": "3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.2",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.3.1",
    "typings": "0.8.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "webpack": "1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "0.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  }
}
```

Comment: npm v3.x flattens things out.  Other folks seem to have also seen this, so I think this is a duplicate.  You can decide if so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722727/npm-packages-not-nesting-in-visual-studio-with-latest-node

Comment: From what he's describing that sounds like what's going on.  I'll test tonight and close if it is a duplicate.